# GRUB menu not appearing

Tags: grub2

I have a laptop with windows XP installed.

I installed ubuntu 13 as a dual boot and everthing appeared okay

Later on I booted with windows and since then the GRUB menu is never displayed when the machine is booted.

If I use a USB to boot ubuntu I can see the various linux and windows partitions

What should I do?

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Once you boot Ubuntu when you use a USB. Open terminal and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```